# Compare two POJO objects in Java and display the difference

Tags: java, arrays, object, pojo

I need to compare two Pojo objects and display the result.

My scenario is to compare Db value with input file. For that I have created a POJO class.

**POJO Class**

```
public class BuySellTO
{
String fundFamily;

public String getFundFamily() {
    return fundFamily;
}

public void setFundFamily(String fundFamily) {
    this.fundFamily = fundFamily;
}
```

**Method for Reading values in DB**

```
public BuySellTO readDB(String x) throws Exception {
    try {
        String sqlQuery;
        BuySellTO bsDb = new BuySellTO();
        if(x.isEmpty() || StringUtils.isBlank(x))
           sqlQuery = "----sql query----";
        else
            sqlQuery = "----sql query----";
        ResultSet result = sqlDb.executeSqlQuery(sqlQuery);
        while (result.next()) {
            bsDb.setFundFamily(result.getString(1).trim());
          }
        return bsDb;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
```

**Method for Reading values in Input File**

```
public BuySellTO readFundDetailsInFile(String a, String b) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        BuySellTO inputTO = new BuySellTO();
        String[] data = readBuySellFile(a, b);
        if (data != null) {
            inputTO.setFundFamily(data[0].trim());
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Record does not exist in the File to store in Array..!!!");
        return inputTO;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Here, I will have 'n' number of fields. So I need to compare one by one and print the result.

I can directly compare using below method.

**compare**

```
public static boolean comparePOJO(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
    return new Gson().toJson(obj1).equals(new Gson().toJson(obj2));
}
```

Kindly provide your ideas to compare each objects individually.

Comment: It depends on what you want to compare. If you only wwant to know whether the two objects are equal, override the `equals` method. If you want to find the differences, you could use reflection to access all fields.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the equals method?

You need to override them in BySellTO class.

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof BuySellTO)) return false;

        BuySellTO buySellTO = (BuySellTO) o;

        return fundFamily != null ? fundFamily.equals(buySellTO.fundFamily) : buySellTO.fundFamily == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return fundFamily != null ? fundFamily.hashCode() : 0;
    }
```

And then

```
public static boolean comparePOJO(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
    return obj1.equals(obj2);
}
```

Comment: If I need to compare for 10 fields. How to achieve this..??

Comment: If you are using eclipse you can automatically generate `equals` and `hashcode`. Remember to override `hashcode` if you are overriding `equals`. Saves a lot of pain down the line.

Comment: @MohanKumar You need to override equals in POJO class. Simply you can use auto-generated one from IDE.

Comment: Hi, I believe inside your reading values from DB method, you had overwrite the 'bsDb.setFundFamily(...)'. May try to use readFundDetailsInFile(a,b) function to return data, and compare it inside 'Reading values in DB' while/for loop...